# Externalize web.xml filter init param value

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml, externalizing

I have the below filter in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>test</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.test.MyFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>loginUrl</param-name>
        <param-value>https://loginAppName</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Here loginUrl is different in different environments. So I want to externalize this param value.
How to do this?

Comment: Not possible with stock Java EE. The answer depends on build system used and targeted server(s). Which are you using/targeting? E.g. Maven build system and WildFly server support it.

Comment: I moved the properties to catalina.properties file and it's working now. Thanks for the information.